# Orange, K-means clustering, memory error

Tags: data-mining, clustering, k-means, orange

I have a dataset of over 67 000 records, and I'm trying to run a k-means cluster analysis on that. Orange returns a memory error.
The data is in an excel file, but I also tried to load it from a csv. Omitting some records and downsizing it under 65k records also couldnt help.
Hierarchical clustering also doesnt work for the same reason.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to do here?

Error code:

> MemoryError
>   Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\gui.py", line 2220, in
>   
>       b.button = btn = button(b, master, label, callback=lambda: do_commit())   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\gui.py", line 2191, in
>   do_commit
>       commit()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\unsupervised\owkmeans.py",
>   line 246, in run
>       self.run_optimization()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\widgets\unsupervised\owkmeans.py",
>   line 225, in run_optimization
>       self.optimization_runs.append((k, kmeans(self.data)))
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\projection\base.py", line 28, in
>   **call**
>       clf = self.fit(data.X, data.Y)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Orange\clustering\kmeans.py", line 23,
>   in fit
>       proj = proj.fit(X, Y)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 821,
>   in fit
>       n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 277,
>   in k_means
>       tol = _tolerance(X, tol)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\k_means_.py", line 162,
>   in _tolerance
>       variances = np.var(X, axis=0)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2938,
>   in var
>       keepdims=keepdims)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py", line 102, in
>   _var
>       x = asanyarray(arr - arrmean)
>   MemoryError

Comment: Can you please provide the error and the code you are using to try to load the csv file?

Comment: just added that to the original post. Thanks!
With regards to loading the CSV, I'm using the GUI, havent written any codes to do that.

Comment: You said you tried downsampling from 67k to 65k. Try to be more drastic and downsample to 30k or even less. You need to do some debugging like that so that we can narrow down the bug.

Comment: 67k records of how many features, i.e. how wide?

Answer (score 1):

Only 32-bit Orange is currently [available for Windows](http://orange.biolab.si/download/windows/) (the filename says win32, if you look). So your per-process RAM is limited to 4 GB. The exception says you ran out of RAM.

Use [64-bit Anaconda installer](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to get 64-bit Python and libraries on Windows, and then install Orange 3 there.